# How should I be exercising during the Ramadan?

Tags: exercise

With the start of Ramadan, I will be fasting for approximately 12 hours a day (no food or water). **Is there any weight loss benefits to running towards the end of the day?**

My thoughts being that my sugar reserves would be bottoming out by then. Also, I am a vegetarian so should I try to get more protein when I break my fast?

In the past, I have run or cycled after longer fasts on 40C days, so I know I can do it.

Comment: Recommended / Related reading: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/592/experience-and-references-about-intermittent-fasting

Comment: I still wouldn't do it. Not drinking water in such high temperatures is dangerous enough, additionally exerting yourself is just begging for dehydration or something worse.

Comment: Are you sure that you aren't even allowed water? I strongly doubt that.

Comment: @Lagerbae - Yep, no food or water from sunrise to sunset. Your body adapts quickly. Even in summer (40+C) dehydration is not a big problem, but I am a white collar worker.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It can be done, but it is not easy.  Take a look at an article posted by Medhi about [Ramadan & Weightlifting](http://stronglifts.com/ramadan-weight-lifting-training-build-muscle-lose-fat/).  While you aren't weightlifting, some of the principles can be applied in your situation.  The high points will be listed below:

- Train 2 hours before you break your fast.  That way you can get several meals in to help your recovery.
- Reduce your training load.  You simply won't be able to recover as fast.
- Nap to preserve energy and get the rest you need

Now, if you intend on running, that will dehydrate you something fierce.  In that case, I recommend changing Medhi's advice to training at the time you break your fast.  That will allow you to remain hydrated, and get some serious food in you right afterwards.  He even provides a schedule to help plan your day in the article.

That said, you will need to eat some caloric dense foods, and food with plenty of protein.

Comment: I personally am not muslim, but I do fast from time to time, so I stumbled across that article when I was wondering how to train fasted.

Answer (score 3):

I'm muslim and I love to run. Ramadan is a tremendouse challenge physically and mentally this month, with that being said I have actually decreased my running to 2 miles a day from 3 miles at least 30 minutes before I break fast and I find it very rewarding. I still work up a good sweat and have a 32 oz sports drink ready with some fruit.

You really have to listen to your body on this one. I also take a nap during the day for at least 2 hours which is very beneficial and gives you a little more pep in your step. Mentally I feel very sharp and in tune with what Ramadan is all about.

As for weights I use a 10 pound medicine ball for about 15 to 20 minutes and I also spend at least 20 minutes on the floor with stretching and deep breathing. You just have to take it easy and cut your normal routine in half and you should be good to go.

**Remember to drink plenty of water after fasting and before the fast begins.**